# What is the best way to swap hard drives in cassandra

Tags: datastax, cassandra-2.1, nosql

we have dense nodes. (~1TB per node; 8 node cluster. DSC 2.1.13; RF=3). we are planning on moving SSDs from spinning disks. what is the best way of doing this?

Approach 1: nodetool decommission -> going to take for ever to re-distribute all the data across the ndoes.

Approach 2: nodetool removednode HostUUID -> Per my research also takes time to re-distribute keys

Approach 3: shutdown node-> swap the drives-> nodetool repair.

Thanks!

Comment: what's your  consistency level setting?

Comment: you have got RF3, so you could do no-downtime (assuming, you do not require strong consistency by a client) disk swap using Approach 3

Answer (score 0):

Go with approach 3 and you can copy everything from that drive to ssd and reboot node to shorten the process. If you can do it under hinted handoff window you will have that node up and in consistent state in no time. Make sure your clients don't crash if they use strict consistency levels as already stated by other two comments.